# localisation of website using gettext

Tags: php, localization, gettext, po, mo

I have to translate the text in english to germany.For that I have done the folllownig
I have used gettext and working on Ubuntu 11.10 os...

1. created a **text.php**
2. Through Poedit created **messages.po** and **messages.mo**(automatically created).

   Both .po and .mo file reside in "locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES."
3. Then created the localization.php in the same location where the file text.php resides.

But still When I tested the file text.php it gave output as untranslated string....

Why was it so? Have done any mistake or left something else......?

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Please show the code from your `text.php` and `localization.php`

Answer (score 0):

Gettext is not magic. It doesn't translate output on its own when localization files exist; you have to explicitly call the `gettext()` function whenever you want it to translate a string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php, the example shows which initialization to do before the `gettext()` or `_()` functions actually translate text.